# Solving for $a$ and $b$

Tags: quadratics

How would you solve the equality:
$$a\,b\,\left(b+a\right)=1$$
in terms of a and/or b? 
Would you subtract 1 from both sides and work from there? Or would you simply expand and work from there?

Comment: You could solve a quadratic in $a$ or $b$ (the equation is symmetrical in $a,b$).

Comment: Quadratic Formula sounds good. Treat separately the case $a=0$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you, I didn't spot that!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of closure I'll "answer" Pedro's answer in the comments. we have $ab^2+a^2b-1=0$, so we can use the quadratic equation to solve for one in terms of the other. This yields

$$b=\frac{-a^\frac{3}{2}\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2\sqrt{a}}$$

Comment: There's a typo in your solution (it should be $a^2+4$) and you've been missing one branch of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b=ta$ for $t\notin\{-1,0\}$.  Then $1=a^3t(t+1)$, that is $a=1/\sqrt[3]{t(t+t)}$ and $b=t/\sqrt[3]{t(t+1)}$.